# Why does SetWindowsHookEx return 0?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to set a `WH_CBT` hook, and it return 0 all the time.
I checked for error, and I got error 1428. I researched a little and found out that I have a problem with the `hMod` parameter, though I can't see what should I put in it instead of `null`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

HHOOK hookHandle;

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc( int nCode,  WPARAM wParam,  LPARAM lParam);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT,CBTProc,NULL,0);

 if(hookHandle == NULL) 
 {
  cout << "ERROR CREATING HOOK: ";
  cout << GetLastError() << endl;
  getchar();
  return 0;
 }

 MSG message;

 while(GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) != 0) 
 {
  TranslateMessage( &message );
  DispatchMessage( &message );
 }



 cout << "Press any key to quit...";
 getchar();

 UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookHandle);

 return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc( int nCode,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
cout << "hello" << endl;
    return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode, 
            wParam, lParam);
}
```

P.S. I apologize if the code has stupid elements about it. I'm not a newbie to programming, just to C++.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify 0 for the threadid that specifies the hook to be global. For that to work, the hook needs to be injected into other processes. This means the hook needs to be exposed from a DLL. You need to either move the hook procedure to a dll, or specify a thread in your process.

Comment: hey, just a question, is it possible to do the hook installation within the .dll (where the hook proc is at) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` and `GetCurrentThreadId()` to get the handle and the thread id you need to pass to that function.

Sample:

```
hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT,CBTProc,
                              GetModuleHandle(NULL),  
                              GetCurrentThreadId());
```

As Logan says, that would hook only the current process. You need to put the code in a dll to develop a system hook.

Comment: how? can you give me an example please?

Comment: check passing the current thread id as Cody said. But remember this hook only will capture messages for its same process... I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, but what do i have to do to capture messages for all of the processes currently running?

Comment: Good answer from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454477/global-hook-setwindowshookex

Comment: GetModuleHandle(NULL) cannot work here, this is an EXE.  Getting the code into a DLL is very necessary to get this going.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is very old post, but I was fighting with the simmilar issue. I wanted to track size and location changes for the "Shell_traywnd" window and I found a solution in [this thread](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210104-00/?p=104656). I belive that it will help for someone else.