# SetWindowsHookEx for WH_KEYBOARD (Global) Without using Dll?

Tags: delphi, setwindowshookex

i'm trying to make my hook work globaly inside a process, it worked for me using the _LL (LowLevel) one, when setting *hMod* and *dwTID* to 0.

is there a way to make it work without a .dll ?

Comment: What do you mean "without a DLL?" Please try and give some more detail on your exact scenario.

Comment: You NEED a DLL because that DLL will be loaded into each and every process that runs and needs to call the hook. The hook will not be called in the context of your EXE, and you're going to have a lot of fun "talking" to your own exe! See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550074/setwindowshookex-creates-a-local-hook-how-to-make-it-global

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Cosmin understood me...

Comment: @CosminPrund: out of curiousity, how come the LowLevel one doesn't need a .dll ?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes, i should have opened both eyes :o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. The requirement is mentioned nearly in every place that talks about or give examples of global hooks on MSDN. Some examples:

[Hook Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#procedures)

> ... A global hook procedure can be called in the context of any
>   application in the same desktop as the calling thread, so the
>   procedure must be in a separate DLL module. ...

[Installing and Releasing Hook Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#installing_releasing)

> ... You must place a global hook procedure in a DLL separate from the
>   application installing the hook procedure. ...

[SetWindowsHookEx function (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> ... All global hook functions must be in libraries. ...

Note that the reason might be that *the code can be run in context of other applications* as per the documentation, but this is not always the case - also mentioned in the documentation. From `SetWindowsHookEx`:

> ... Be aware that the WH_MOUSE, WH_KEYBOARD, WH_JOURNAL*, WH_SHELL, and
>   low-level hooks can be called on the thread that installed the hook
>   rather than the thread processing the hook. ...

I don't really know what the *can* really means in that statement. Is it sometimes that way and sometimes the othwer way, but I only conducted one test, and the hook procedure is called indeed in the context of the thread that installed the hook, rendering unnecessary any interprocess communication. This doesn't change the requirement for the *dll* however.

The processing of low level hooks is simply different. As explained to some extent in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the call to the hook is done by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook and then switching the context to that thread - which does not require installing a dll.

Comment: As @kevin-edwards said, WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL can set global hook without DLL. It is very useful when you just want to hack something quickly. I used to use the hook to write my own game bot, which works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify, WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL are low level global hooks that do not require a dll (the other hooks like WH_KEYBOARD do require a dll to inject into other processes):

[Applying low-level keyboard hooks with Python and SetWindowsHookExA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817531/applying-low-level-keyboard-hooks-with-python-and-setwindowshookexa)

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to hook into one or more external processes, you must implement the hook inside of a DLL as the hook code needs to be injected into the address space of those processes, and only a DLL can do that.

If you intend to hook just your own calling process, you do not need a DLL, but you must call `SetWindowsHookEx()` on a per-thread basis to install thread-specific hooks, ie you have to set the `hMod` value to `NULL` and the `dwThreadId` parameter to a non-zero value, such as from `GetCurrentThreadId()` or `CreateThread()`.