# Intercept and transform key signals to a process in C++ or any other language

Tags: process, keyboard, key, language-agnostic, intercept

I want to intercept Russian keys in a specific application and send it something else. I don't really know the steps required to achieve it.

Is there a way to write an app in C++ that captures key presses and sends different ones to a specific program, process?

Comment: Is the _"specific application"_ an application you own and have the source code to?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Nope, I don't own the code. It is a standalone app, an exe.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I had to find the answer myself so I've duckduckgoed and found this: [C++ KeyBoard hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493394/c-keyboard-hook)

Seems like I have to inject a DLL in a process and call SetWindowsHookExA function that supposedly ought to intercept and transform key events that are sent to the process.